# What files should be deleted if i don't want anyone to know if the system has been once linked to the internet?

Tags: logs, logrotate, trace, var

For certain reasons I have to delete all files that might indicate that the syatem has once been linked to the internet. I have deleted all the records in browser, and the internet ethernet address. What else I can do, such that no one is able to know that the system has linked to the internet? Can I delete all files in var/log? This is a new system with only the anaconda and relavant pachakges been installed.

Comment: Couple of files immediately come to mind. `.bash_history` for any curl or wget commands. `/etc/yum.repos.d` or `/etc/apt` files for default repositories that have been used for installation or updates. Firewall logs on your default gateway. `arp` tables listing out-of-network connections. Existence of a default route to the internet. Other items are probably likely.

Comment: you could always just reinstall it.